# Is there a way to cover a hole for cables that does not require a wall box?

Tags: walls, hole, cable-management, cover

Is there a way to cover a hole for cables that does not require a wall box?

I expressly had a cable conduit installed in our TV nicho, but in the end, my equipment is up higher on the wall (above where the conduit starts). I want to run the cables through the wall, instead of having them hanging down. My plan was to drill a hole into the wall and run the cables down to the top of the cable conduit. I do not have the skills or equipment to install a wall box (and the wall is made entirely of 2x4's, to enable hanging a TV), and most of the wall cable covers I have found (the kinds with the pair of bristles) have tabs that stick into a wall box.

Are there any good options that simply screw into sheetrock, rather than install into a wall box?

Answer (score 1):

These work nice. I use them often.

[image]

http://www.mycablemart.com/store/cart.php?m=product_detail&p=850

You can use them with these:

http://www.mycablemart.com/store/cart.php?m=product_detail&relate=1&p=885

Comment: Looks good, but I may not be able to create a hole big enough to enable installing one.

Answer (score 0):

Installing an "old work box" only requires a screw driver and a jab saw (which can be had for under $10), and doesn't require much more skill than drilling a hole in the wall. It will give you a much more durable anchor for cover plates than anything attached directly to the drywall (and you can cut a bigger hole for easier access to the wall's interior)

Comment: When cutting holes in drywall, a razor (utility) knife (or just a good sharp knife) is all you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, the location is more than just drywall, it is drywall over a layer of 2x4's (for mounting a TV in the nicho). I think I will need more skill and tools than those.

Comment: A razor knife is fine for scoring and snapping drywall. It is NOT however the tool of choice for cutting holes.